# BroadcastReceiver not working in HTC desire 601

Tags: android, android-broadcast

I have designed a call screen using the concept of BroadcastReceiver .
Also I have used below provided code in the manifest file.

```
<receiver android:name="com.pcs.incomingreciever.IncomingReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

I have also added Android READ PHONE STATE permission in my Manifest file. 
My code working perfectly in Other devices.
But it's not working in HTC desire mobile particularly.

Comment: does it show any error ? show some logcat

Comment: Show some code and the logcat. As far as my experience goes, I have used PHONE_STATE as a permission to receive Intents such as screen_on/off...., not as a broadcast intent filter itself.

Comment: it is not showing  any kind of error in my logcat....

Comment: @Josh Sir i have already added Android READ PHONE STATE permission in my Manifest file. but its not working in HTC devices. for other device my code working fine...i have tried to debug my app by adding break point in onRecieve() method.when i am calling to My htc device from other device even control not coming to that breakpont line in my Callscreen class.